# Edges per vertex in polyhedron

Tags: geometry

Which polyhedra have no more than 3 edges per vertex?

limitations:  No more than 20 faces.  Convex polyhedra only.  No limit to the number of vertices.  No limit to the number of edges, only to the number of edges-per-vertex.  The polyhedra need not be regular.

I know Tetrahedron and hexahedron (cube, and variants) qualify.  Are there any others and, if so, what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot.

Tetrahedron, Cube, Dodecahedron, Duerer Solid, all prisms with number of sides less than 18.

Then you can take any of above and truncate any number of vertices (while number of faces does not exceed 20). If you haven't reached 20 faces, you can repeat truncation.

Then you can take a polyhedron with 4 edges at vertex and if it has faces+vertices<20, truncation of all vertices will get you a proper polyhedron like Truncated Octrahedron.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is a Duerer Solid just a variation on a truncated (specifically on the "top" and "bottom" vertices) cube/hexahedron?  a hexahedron (stretched cube) with 2 vertices truncated?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

Truncation replaces a vertex by a further face, its vertex figure. Thus that new face does intersect the former faces in new edges. Two neighbouring ones of those run towards one of the old edges each. The new vertices are obtained by intersection of the vertex figure face with the old edges. And those thus are bound to be threevalent.

For any specific but arbitrary convex polyhedron $P$ call $V$ its vertex count, $V_3$ the count of its threevalent vertices, and $F$ the count of its faces.

Now consider the subset of all convex polyhedra, which bow to $F+(V-V_3)\le 20$. Simply by truncating any non-threevalent vertex of either of its members you'd get a polyhedron which follows your requirements.

--- rk